# How to convert Excel file with multiple sheets to CSV at once using azure logic app?

Tags: excel, azure, csv, azure-logic-apps

I want to convert Excel file with multiple sheets to csv at once using logic app , Im able to convert perticular sheet(only 1 at a time) from excel file to csv but not all of them at once. Any help/suggestion would be appreciated

Thanks in advance

Comment: What should be the result? One file per sheet or a single file with content of all sheets? In the latter case: How should the data within all sheets be merged into a single table?

Comment: If you are able to convert one sheet from excel to a file, would you mind to share your code to improve it to solve your problem?

Comment: Is this on your desktop or the cloud? If the Excel file is on your desktop, you can easily use VBA to do the conversion.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hope you are using [Get Tables](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#get-tables) action, then it returns all the tables in any of the worksheets.

You can now loop in through the output of Get Tables action and use ["list rows present in a table"](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/connectors/excelonlinebusiness/#list-rows-present-in-a-table) action.

[image]

On the Table option Select `Enter custom value` and Select the dynamic content `Name` of your previous "Get Tables" action.

[image]

*As you have already mentioned that you were able to convert one table to csv. The next actions should be inside the same, use `FOR LOOP` to save the table rows to csv.*

Reference: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/514894/how-to-convert-excel-file-with-multiple-sheets-to.html